# Is it possible to expose nalgebra matrix types to python via pyo3 in rust

Tags: rust, pyo3, nalgebra

I'm able to expose simple functions written in Rust to python using pyo3 but can see no way to expose complex "eigen" / matrix types.  Does anyone know if this is possible?

lib.rs

```
extern crate nalgebra as na;    
use pyo3::prelude::*;
use na::{SMatrix, Vector3, Matrix3};

/// Formats the sum of two numbers as string.
#[pyfunction]
fn sum_as_string(a: usize, b: usize) -> PyResult<String> {
    Ok((a + b).to_string())
}


#[pyfunction]
fn matrix_math(v3: Vector3<f64>, m3x3: Matrix3<f64>) -> PyResult<SMatrix<f64, 3, 1>>{
    let mxv = m3x3 * v3;
    Ok(mxv)
}

// Neiter way works

type Matrix3f = Matrix3<f64>;
type Vector3f = Vector3<f64>;

#[pyfunction]
fn matrix_math_w_types(v3: Vector3f, m3x3: Matrix3f) -> PyResult<SMatrix<f64, 3, 1>>{
    let mxv = m3x3 * v3;
    mxv
}

#[pymodule]
fn libpytest(_py: Python, m: &PyModule) -> PyResult<()> {
    m.add_function(wrap_pyfunction!(sum_as_string, m)?)?;
    m.add_function(wrap_pyfunction!(matrix_math, m)?)?;

    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: I don't know PyO3, but I suspect that the issue is that it can't expose generic types. Try to create a type alias, e.g. `type Matrix3f = Matrix3<f64>`, and expose that to your Python API.

Comment: @Jmb Thanks, it was worth a try but no joy.  I was hoping it would work like the pybind11 stuff in C++ that includes eigen vector / matrix types.   I suspect there is a way but will need to keep searching.

Comment: You would need to have a type alias also for the return type, or convert the `SMatrix<f64, 3, 1>` into a `Vector3f` and return that.

Comment: @Jmb yes.  I did try that as well but it seems that pyo3 just does not support nalgebra bindings.  Looks like they do support ndarray which I have not explored.  Eigen is the defacto matrix lib for C++ but I gather that ndarray is the defactor matrix library for Rust.  Thank you again for your response.